# Why LIMIT Clause failing for JSON_ARRAYAGG function?

Tags: mysql

The limit clause seems to be not working when JSON_ARRAYAGG function is used.

Is there any better way to achieve the functionality ?

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TABLE ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2;
--> Gives me 2 random employee details - which is perfect.

SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('userId', user_id)) FROM USER_TABLE ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2;
--> Gives me ALL the employee details. - which is INCORRECT.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` without a `GROUP BY` clause you will get only one row. Only then is `LIMIT 2` applied, and (of course) doesn't have any effect on that single row. What you probably need is a `LIMIT 2` subquery in the FROM clause:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(json_obj)
FROM (
    SELECT JSON_OBJECT('userId', user_id) as json_obj
    FROM USER_TABLE
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 2
) x
```

or

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('userId', user_id))
FROM (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM USER_TABLE
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 2
) x
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and response. This was new to me :)